# exec: "docker-runc": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using ubuntu 18.04 
after upgrading docker to "Docker version 18.09.0-ce-tp5, build 9eb3d36"

Everything works fine before updating docker

Getting following error on docker-compose up:

> ERROR: for mysql_1  Cannot start service mysql: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/242793c2e7ad05e93ccff53ae37e5d8b054a72f9c2076c1b480f33929dbb45aa/log.json: no such file or directory): exec: "docker-runc": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

docker info gives

```
linux@linux-linux:/$ docker info
Containers: 14
 Running: 14
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1091
Server Version: 18.09.0-ce-tp5
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 1038
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: containerd runc
Default Runtime: containerd
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: ce243288e27971e324363de8f322d221635a8521 (expected: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e)
runc version: 1555a78945e56737bc3d15565191d857ee6fa2b9 (expected: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340)
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-32-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.719GiB
Name: linux-linux
ID: F475:F7JY:3HSG:XLGM:BAPD:CZYD:HRRO:SN3N:SFSX:7XOK:VDZ4:SNMV
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using ubuntu 18.04 after upgrading docker to "Docker version 18.09.0-ce-tp5, build 9eb3d36"

The TP# releases are pre beta (I suspect it stands for technical preview). These will have issues, and there were lots of changes with the containerd integration. You can try upgrading to beta1, or go back to the stable 18.06.1 release. You can see the releases here:

https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**
I faced the same issue.

**Solution**
first i restart docker,but when i tried to start my container i was having Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container with id exists:xxxxxxxxxx

but in ps -a it was showing nothing.
while i was able to run the new  container using the same id.

than tried 
reboot my server and it is working fine.

Comment: This sounds like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io/+bug/1836022 ...

Answer (score 0):

as you can see in this 2 rows:

```
containerd version: ce243288e27971e324363de8f322d221635a8521 (expected: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e)
runc version: 1555a78945e56737bc3d15565191d857ee6fa2b9 (expected: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340)
```

docker expects another internal **container id** as the tagged container has. i guess this causes the problem.
have you tried to rebuild your container?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem.
Try committing your container.
Then run it again.
e.g.
docker commit RUNNING_CONTAINER  IMAGE1
docker run -d IMAGE1

Answer (score 0):

`service docker restart` solved the problem in my case

Comment: service restart not solved, but machine restart solved in my case.